# Laravel - spatie permissions delete permission issue inside phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-permission

I am having some trouble with spatie/laravel permissions package.

The issue is with one of my tests failing for deleting a permission directly through testing. The same approach using postman works as expected.

The error i am getting is:

`` SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a259dc99655f' (SQL: delete from `user_permissions` where `model_id` = 49 and `model_type` = Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission) ``

Is this a known issue or am i missing something.

Comment: also, i am using laravel lumen 7x

Comment: `Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a259dc99655f'` Have you checked the datatypes on your MySQL tables?

Comment: I can add a permission through an POST endpoint in postman and then delete it using postman.  Its when i run in phpunit create permission `x` then run $this->delete('permission/x'), it gives me this error

Comment: The data types look correct, could it be the version i am on which is ^3.11 for spatie

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It is a lumen issue with the latest version i think.

It was to do with db strict mode.

I added this  `<env name="DB_STRICT_MODE" value="false" force="true" />` to the phpunit test config.

I found it from this post `https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/disable-strict-mode-mysql-in-latest-lumen`

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your issue :) . Were you using MySQL for your test database driver? Or SQLite ?

Comment: it was mysql in a separate instance using docker